# .NET StringReader or TextAsset not reading certain characters at all

Tags: .net, mono, stringreader

My code:

```
StringReader tr = null;
TextAsset data = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("data.ext", typeof(TextAsset));
tr = new StringReader(data.text);   
sTemp = tr.ReadLine();
Debug.Log(sTemp);
```

data.ext file:

```
00!%%%£r!%%%£122222230e0e01255
```

My output:

```
00!%%%r!%%%122222230e0e01255
```

As you can see StringReader (or possibly TextAsset) doesn't seem to like the £ character. I thought there might be some strange escape type of character which I didn't know about
I have looked on the .net and unity docs, but I can't find any explanation or any mention about special characters.

This one has me completely stumped. I am compiling in Unity3D which uses mono .NET. I might do some tests using the official .NET compiler.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint and check the content of `data.text` right after the assignment of `data`?

Comment: Found the solution. I saved my text file with UTF8 encoding and now everything is fine. No changes to the code were needed.

Comment: you can post an answer to your own question, it may help others in the future. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I was going to, but was restricted not to answer within 6 hours or posting, or something to that extent, which is why I posted my answer in the comment above. I can copy and paste the comment if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I saved my text file with UTF8 encoding and now everything is fine. No changes to the code were needed.